# Composing std::integral_constant values

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

Consider this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum Thing {Thing0, Thing1, Thing2, NumThings};
enum Object {Object0, Object1, Object2, NumObjects};

template <Thing> struct ThingValue;

template <> struct ThingValue<Thing0> : std::integral_constant<int, 5> {};
template <> struct ThingValue<Thing1> : std::integral_constant<int, 2> {};
template <> struct ThingValue<Thing2> : std::integral_constant<int, 12> {};

template <Object> struct ObjectValue;

template <> struct ObjectValue<Object0> : std::integral_constant<Thing, Thing2> {};
template <> struct ObjectValue<Object1> : std::integral_constant<Thing, Thing0> {};
template <> struct ObjectValue<Object2> : std::integral_constant<Thing, Thing1> {};

int main() {
    std::cout << ThingValue<ObjectValue<Object0>::value>::value << '\n';  // 12
}
```

I'm trying to define, `ComposeValues<T, Value, Pack...>` so that the above in main() can be written as `ComposeValues<Object, Object0, ThingValue, ObjectValue>::value`.  So then this can be extended to any number of such compositions.  Not an absolutely vital thing to do, but I'd figure that it would be a nice little exercise to define such a thing.  But I'm having difficulty with the syntax:

```
template <typename T, T Value, template <typename> class...> struct ComposeValues;

template <typename T, T Value, template <typename> class First, template <typename> class... Rest>
struct ComposeValues<T, Value, First, Rest...> {
    static auto value = First<typename ComposeValues<T, Value, Rest...>::value>::value;
};

template <typename T, T Value, template <T> class Last>
struct ComposeValues<T, Value, Last> : std::integral_constant<T, Last<Value>::value> {};  // Won't compile.
```

Is this even possible what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that you can't mix template templates which take different non-type arguments. In your example, this means that `ObjectValue` and `ThingValue` cannot bind to `template <typename> class...`.

A way to fix this is to encode your enums in some type kind of template which can hold both of them indiscriminately. A possible way to do this is just treat the enums as `int`s and let the user worry about passing in reasonable types.

First we create wrappers around your current types:

```
template <typename> struct ThingValueWrapper;
template <int I>
struct ThingValueWrapper<std::integral_constant<int,I>> 
    : ThingValue<static_cast<Thing>(I)>
{};

template <typename> struct ObjectValueWrapper;
template <int I>
struct ObjectValueWrapper<std::integral_constant<int, I>> 
    : ObjectValue<static_cast<Object>(I)>
{};
```

Then we can do something pretty similar to what you originally had:

```
template <typename T, T Value, template <typename> class...> struct ComposeValues;

template <typename T, T Value, 
          template <typename> class First, 
          template <typename> class... Rest>
struct ComposeValues<T, Value, First, Rest...>
    : std::integral_constant<int,
                             First<typename ComposeValues<T, Value, Rest...>::type>::value>
{};

template <typename T, T Value>
struct ComposeValues<T, Value> : std::integral_constant<int, static_cast<int>(Value)> {};
```

The only difference from your original use-case is that we need to use our wrappers instead of the original enum traits:

```
ComposeValues<Object, Object0, ThingValueWrapper, ObjectValueWrapper>::value
```

Comment: One downside to this is that the final type is erased, but you could handle this pretty easily with doing a final cast to `T`.

Comment: Ok, I studied your solution and I got it.  But your last suggestion of writing `ComposeValues<Object, Object0, Wrap<ThingValue>, Wrap<ObjectValue>>::value` will run into the same problem as my original problem, won't it?  Since `ThingValue` and `ObjectValue` are not types but templates (that use different non-type arguments).  If we could write it this way, or `ComposeValues<Object, Object0, Wrap<ThingValue, ObjectValue>>::value`, then my original method would be possible too, right?   I don't see how `ThingValueWrapper` and `ObjectValueWrapper` can be nicely parametrized into a family.

Comment: @prestokeys You're absolutely right, I just wrote that without thinking.